# Cannot make command line tool for artisan in PHPStorm 10.0.1

Tags: php, xml, phpstorm, laravel-artisan, laravel-5

I got this error message when I tried to make an alias for artisan:
[Settings | Tools | Command Line Tool Support ] -> add -> tool based on Symfony Console

Problem

```
Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 4: Content is not allowed in prolog..
```

Command

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\laratest\artisan list --xml
```

Output

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
The "--xml" option does not exist.
```

Ok, I know, what's the problem but I don't find any solution for this. 
Thank you for the tips!

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29627 ? See if it will work in next version (10.0.3 I guess).

Comment: Even better -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27653

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A temporal modification of the "artisan" file under the Laravel folder will do the trick. (Working on PhpStorm 10.0.3)

```
if( isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == 'list' && 
    isset($argv[2]) && $argv[2] == '--xml' ) {
    $argv[2] = '--format=xml';
    $_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;
}
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Now you can add the "artisan" command line tool support based on Symfony and remove the lines if you wish to.

Answer (score 1):

For everybody affected, this is the commit which removed support for –xml: https://github.com/symfony/console/commit/6d6d9031b9148fed0e2aacb98ac23ce6168ba7ac

Just revert changes in ListCommand.php

it work in 2.7 version

Answer (score 0):

There is no `--xml` option, you are getting this error when you running this command:

> The "--xml" option does not exist.

So what you should do in this case is running:

```
php artisan help list
```

and you will get list of all available parameters

and now you will know you need to use:

```
php artisan list --format=xml
```

instead of:

```
php artisan list --xml
```

**EDIT**

I've verified it in PhpStorm 10.0.3

as Tool path you can paste in your case:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\laratest\artisan list --format=xml
```

and it will work

Comment: Ok I know, but how I can force it in PHPStrom? I can't find that code snippet, where the artisan gets the argument "--xml".

Comment: Oops, I was happy too soon. Maybe, I could do it wrong but I can't paste it. 
So in the "tool based on Symfony Console" -> "Path to script" i tried to paste C:\xampp\htdocs\laratest\artisan list --format=xml but it accepts only path to file. Maybe you thought about the Custom tool?

Comment: @RostásIstván Yeah, I used custom one, not based on Symfony

Comment: @RostásIstván Yeah, but I would use different name than `artisan` because this command only displays you possible commands in XML format and not allow using artisan commands

Answer (score -1):

Update composer before add command line tool:

```
composer update
```