# Netbeans Symfony : The "--xml" option does not exist.

Tags: xml, symfony, netbeans, command

I am trying to make a first Symfony project (LoginProject) in Netbeans. But I don't get too far. The tutorial tells me:
- to right-click the project
- symfony > run command

then I am getting no available commands in the screen, and I get the error message:

```
     [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--xml" option does not exist.                      


list [--raw] [--format FORMAT] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<namespace>]
```

I have xampp installed, and the LoginProject is under de htdocs, nothing special.

How can i overcome this error?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Please provide a link.

Comment: this is the tutorial i am following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvLk3i2CBgw)

Comment: That tutorial is from 2013, which is really old.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know wich tutorial you are following.

if your Symfony project is not created it is perfectly normal that there are no available commands.

Anyways you should create your project with `symfony new` command of the Symfony installer or `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition` and run your commands from the console with `php app/console`.Don't rely too much on (the unreliable) netbeans.

Here is the tutorial you should be following since it is what Symfony recommends: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Regarding the error, when you

> right-click the project - symfony > run command

netbeans tries to execute a command to show you the available commands in your project.
To do that it calls the command with the --xml option so that the output is in xml and netbeans can parse it.

So either the command it is trying to execute does not have the --xml option or there is just no such command.

Comment: I understand you may not prefer, but for me this is the most familiar. Netbeans creates the new Project, and this goes without problems. I think there must be a way to create the xml option but I do not have an idea how that I can do that. I have read this similar [Q&A] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422376/cannot-make-command-line-tool-for-artisan-in-phpstorm-10-0-1) but I don't understand howto apply this answer to my problem...

Comment: I can see you like to create your projects with netbeans but if it is not working either try to update netbeans or re install it or you will have to try what i suggested to understand what is going wrong